# not able to redirect the output to a file in ipython ide

Tags: linux, ipython

I am not able to redirect the output of dir(modulename) to a file in ipython ide. Please let me know how to do that. It works for the same for ls and other linux commands.

```
 In [45]: os.system('dir(socket) > socket1.txt')
 File Not Found
 Out[45]: 1

 In [46]: os.system('cat socket1.txt')
 Volume in drive C is Local Disk
 Volume Serial Number is D649-B68C

 Directory of C:\Users\aryan\PycharmProjects\classes

 Out[46]: 0

In [47]: dir (socket)
Out[47]:
['AF_APPLETALK',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing two worlds here.

One is the Python world in which you can call Python functions (like `dir()`); in this world redirection is *not* done simply using `>` or similar things.

The other world is the Shell world in which you can call shell command lines (like `cat socket1.txt`); in this world redirection can be done using a simple `>` symbol (together with a file name) after the command.  This world is entered using the `system()` call (or others from the `subprocess` module).

What you are now doing is using `system()` to enter the Shell world and then execute `dir()` in this world (which does not work).  The redirection will work, though, so you will create a file named `socket1.txt` (probably empty).

Redirecting the output of a Python call is a thing not so easily done in general.  Your case, however, is special:  You just want to dump a Python value into a file.  This is easy:

```
with open('socket1.txt', 'w') as out_file:
  out_file.write(str(dir(socket)))
```

Comment: os.system('grep \'timeout\' socket1.txt') is also not working for some reason. following is the truncated output of socket1.txt.                                             
       'herror', 'htonl', 'htons', 'inet_aton', 'inet_ntoa', 'inet_ntop', 'inet_pton', 'io', 'ntohl', 'ntohs', 'os', 'selectors', 'setdefaulttimeout', 'socket', 'socketpair', 'sys', 'timeout']